# curl, API request works in Insomnia, but not in generated code for curl

Tags: api, curl, insomnia

I have request in Insomnia. When I send it via Insomnia, no problemo. But when I generate source code for curl, it shows me this.

```
curl --request POST \
  --url URL \
  --header 'Authorization: bearer XXX' \
  --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001' \
  --cookie JSESSIONID=XXX \
  --form datasetFile=@FOLDER/producthierarchyl1-1.zip

{"message":"Bad Request","logref":null,"path":null,"_embedded":{"errors":[{"message":"Required argument [Publisher datasetFile] not specified","logref":null,"path":"/datasetFile","_embedded":{},"_links":{}}]},"_links":{"self":{"href":"/data-api/public-api/v4/datasets/ingestion/","templated":false,"profile":null,"deprecation":null,"title":null,"hreflang":null,"type":null,"name":null}}}
```

Insomnia output is like this.

```
> POST PATH HTTP/2
> Host: URL
> user-agent: insomnia/2022.3.0
> cookie: JSESSIONID=XXX
> authorization: bearer XXX
> content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY
> accept: */*
> content-length: 407

* STATE: DO => DID handle 0x170404b14008; line 2077 (connection #27)
* multi changed, check CONNECT_PEND queue!
* STATE: DID => PERFORMING handle 0x170404b14008; line 2196 (connection #27)

| --X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY
| Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datasetFile"; filename="producthierarchyl1-1.zip"
| Content-Type: application/zip
| PK�QU�}�%+producthierarchyl1-1.csvUT  բ�b
| --X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY--

* We are completely uploaded and fine
* HTTP/2 found, allow multiplexing
```

Where is the catch?

Thanks.

Comment: @DanielStenberg Wow, you are right. But I don't understand why is header problem, even Insomnia generated it with it. But thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `--header 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001` option.

It really should not be used like this: curl manages that header and the boundary on its own so changing it should only be done in the rare event you truly *want* and *need* to fiddle around with it.

A more minor second thing: `--request POST` should be dropped from the command line, as it is superfluous and easily cause problems if you add `--location` later on.

### Updated

This flaw is said to have been fixed in a later version of Insomnia

Comment: Issue was reported to Insomnia team.

Comment: Hi @genderbee, Filipe from the Insomnia team here! 

This issue has been fixed in later Insomnia versions than the one you are using (2022.3.0).

It was fixed in a PR in a dependency we use, https://github.com/Kong/httpsnippet/pull/227, but the dependency had been only updated to the version with the fix a few months ago.

If you upgrade to latest stable (or beta) release, you should be able to use `Copy as Curl` and shouldn't have this problem. Check over at https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/releases

It has since been fixed

Answer (score 1):

For any folks bumping into this issue again, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73417752/7468990) correctly explains the reason for the problem.

Fortunately this should only be reproducible in versions 2022.3.0 and older versions of Insomnia.

If you use the latest one, [2022.5.1](https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/releases/tag/core%402022.5.1), the generated curl will no longer have this problem, example of a multipart request generated:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url http://mockbin.org/request/anything \
  --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  --form test=test \
  --form test=@/Users/yourUserName/Desktop/somefile.txt
```

Comment: a multipart `GET`, really? and also, that `content-type:` provided header is still superfluous

Comment: It was what I was using purely for example with mockbin.org. As for the `content-type` header, might be something we can improve. EDIT: actually, taking into account all of what you mentioned, yeah, there's still a handful of things we can remove and improve, will try to follow up on this. Thank you Daniel!

Comment: @FilipeFreire Hi Fiilpe, Kristofer Huffman contacted me, I tried latest version, `header` is without `boundary`, but header still present in generated code.