# Curl Works fine on a site but Getting blocked while using requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, curl, python-requests, http-headers

I am trying to make a API call to get reviews from ryviu website.

If I execute the following curl in the terminal, I do get a response from the server.

```
curl 'https://app.ryviu.io/frontend/client/get-more-reviews?domain=tornado-fans.myshopify.com' \
  -H 'authority: app.ryviu.io' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,ur;q=0.6,pa;q=0.5,es;q=0.4' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'dnt: 1' \
  -H 'origin: https://www.tornadofans.com' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.tornadofans.com/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="110"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --data-raw '{"handle":"tornado-24-high-velocity-metal-portable-tilt-blower-drum-fan-yellow-8540-cfm-ul","product_id":7245574144198,"page":2,"type":"load-more","order":"late","filter":"all","feature":false,"domain":"tornado-fans.myshopify.com","platform":"shopify"}' \
  --compressed
```

But if I use Python requests to make the same API call, the requests never succeeds. The code I am using to do this is following -

```py
import requests

url = "https://app.ryviu.io/frontend/client/get-more-reviews?domain=tornado-fans.myshopify.com"

payload='%7B%22handle%22%3A%22tornado-24-high-velocity-metal-portable-tilt-blower-drum-fan-yellow-8540-cfm-ul%22%2C%22product_id%22%3A7245574144198%2C%22page%22%3A2%2C%22type%22%3A%22load-more%22%2C%22order%22%3A%22late%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%22all%22%2C%22feature%22%3Afalse%2C%22domain%22%3A%22tornado-fans.myshopify.com%22%2C%22platform%22%3A%22shopify%22%7D='
headers = {
  'authority': 'app.ryviu.io',
  'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,ur;q=0.6,pa;q=0.5,es;q=0.4',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'dnt': '1',
  'origin': 'https://www.tornadofans.com',
  'referer': 'https://www.tornadofans.com/',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="110"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

With the python request, I am getting the response:

> {"msg":"not found"}

HELP!

I want to know what is the reason curl works but no Python library works.

I have tried everything, I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably your payload not encoded correctly. Taking the dictionnary from your first example, and using `json=` instead of `data=` to provide the payload to the POST request (more on that [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)), I got a positive result:

```
import requests

url = "https://app.ryviu.io/frontend/client/get-more-reviews?domain=tornado-fans.myshopify.com"

payload = {
    "handle": "tornado-24-high-velocity-metal-portable-tilt-blower-drum-fan-yellow-8540-cfm-ul",
    "product_id": 7245574144198,
    "page": 2,
    "type": "load-more",
    "order": "late",
    "filter": "all",
    "feature": False,
    "domain": "tornado-fans.myshopify.com",
    "platform": "shopify"
}
headers = {
  'authority': 'app.ryviu.io',
  'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,ur;q=0.6,pa;q=0.5,es;q=0.4',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'dnt': '1',
  'origin': 'https://www.tornadofans.com',
  'referer': 'https://www.tornadofans.com/',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="110"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, json=payload)

print(response.status_code) # returns 200
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please respond to this also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73416556/curl-api-request-works-in-insomnia-but-not-in-generated-code-for-curl

Comment: @user8087010 Are you sure you pasted the good link, it points to a question that already have an accepted answer ? By the way, if my answer solved your problem, could you accept it then ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75778583/curl-works-in-insomnia-but-does-not-work-in-postman-or-mac-terminal

sorry. posted wrong link. here is the correct link.